# Google Chrome Extension not starting on cloned Linux Ubuntu 20.04 Virtual Machines

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, google-chrome-extensions, xvfb

My own Google Chrome Extension should start when the Google Chrome browser is opened (via crontab xvfb-run), but it does not. The Extension is used via Developer mode and is not published in the Extension Store.

It works fine on my Windows laptop and PC and also on a Linux Ubuntu 20.04 test virtual machine (VM).

On 16 cloned Linux Ubuntu 20.04 VMs, where the Google Chrome browser is opened at exactly the same time, it does not work. I have realized that the Extension has identical IDs for the cloned VMs. On my laptop and PC i have different IDs. **Could this be the reason?**

I have also tried to run the Extension on a fresh VM, but it did not work and the Extension had the same ID like the Extensions on the 16 cloned VMs.

On my test VM it works with the command xvfb-run in a crontab and also with a remote GUI (XLaunch) with Putty.

**Found the solution: For some reason Chrome was started in incognito mode. You have to allow your extension in the 'details' to start in this mode.**

Comment: In the Ubuntu 20.04 VM, was the Google Chrome browser installed as a snap?

Comment: I installed it like this:

wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb 
 ....
sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb 
 ...
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb